# Python Pyprocessmacro causing Runtime Error on installation Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, statsmodels

I'm trying to install the [`pyprocessmacro`](https://github.com/QuentinAndre/pyprocessmacro) library for statistical moderation analysis on a machine running MacOS High Sierra.

When I try:

```
pip install pyprocessmacro
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X
backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not
installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more
information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please
either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other
backends.
```

I notice that this problem seems to afflict people trying to run `matplotlib` on a `virtualenv`. However, none of the solutions proposed for that problem seem to work.

Can anyone advise what might work instead? Thanks!